# Question on $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am confused about some facts on $SL(2,\mathbb R)$.

The Lie algebra of $SL(2,\mathbb R)$ is $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$.
However, the map
$$
\exp:\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)\
\rightarrow SL(2,\mathbb R)
$$
has image
$$
\{g\in SL(2,\mathbb R),\mathrm{Tr}(g)>-2\}\cup\{\pm I\}.
$$
That is to say, the elements $\begin{pmatrix}-1&t\\&-1\end{pmatrix}$ with $t\neq 0$
are not in the image.

Now, Let $G=SL(3,\mathbb{R})$ and $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}(3,\mathbb R)$.
The analytic subgroup of $G$ with Lie algebra
$$
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
a&*&0\\
*&-a&0\\
0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$
is of the form
$$
\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
H&\\
&1
\end{pmatrix}\right\}
$$
So, what is $H$?

$SL(2,\mathbb R)$, $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ or $\exp(\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R))$?

Comment: $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, in my opinion. A Lie group is in general not equal to the image of the exponential of its Lie algebra, as you see. It is just generated by the image. Often, the image of the exponential is not a group at all.

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @PeterFranek, could you remind me why it's not a group? I thought it was a subgroup (since it has the identity element and the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula suggests it is closed under multiplication, right?) but rarely is it the full group...am I mistaken?

Comment: @AlexNelson: you are probably right, sorry for the confusion. I think it is a subgroup but not a Lie subgroup; the differential of $\exp$ is not a local diffeomorphism in the neighborhood of some points -- for example in the neighborhood of $\mathrm{diag}(i\pi,-i\pi)$; the image might be topologically very wild.. But this is already slippery slope for me :)

Comment: The image is not a subgroup, just look at the sl(2,R) case. The CH formula will give you right answers only near 1. As for the question itself, the answer is obviously SL(2,R).

Comment: @studiosus: why? Does the CH not converge? I know this is no more connected to the original question but is interesting anyway..

Comment: As I said, only near the identity.

Comment: If somebody were [interested](https://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublication%2F242986925_On_the_convergence_and_optimization_of_the_BakerCampbellHausdorff_formula%2Ffile%2F5046352987603481e9.pdf&ei=EhWiU_iTFZGv7AbuzoHgDg&usg=AFQjCNHTKIDEQG0i14BoLd66S9yLQ4qg3Q&sig2=fzabwM8REdRDavbAUru6Sg&bvm=bv.69137298,d.ZGU&cad=rja)..